# NetBeans 11.0 is using sources from Maven instead of other open project

Tags: java, maven, debugging, netbeans

I'm trying to do the following: I have a Maven project what I would like to set breakpoints on code from a dependency. The dependency is an other project which I have open in NetBeans, but is also available in my Maven repository, including its source code. Whenever I set a breakpoint in the project's code it's not used by the debugger. However, whenever I set a breakpoint in the Maven dependencies source code it is used!

Also, when I <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+click a reference to the dependency project from my main project, I end up in the Maven source (`.sources.jar`) instead of the project source. So I'm unable to edit and need to navigate to that file in the other project in order to start editing.

Is there some configuration to prevent this from happening? It was working fine with NetBeans 8.2.

Comment: What about if your remove the dependency from your repository until you have completed your development of the other project?

Comment: I'm afraid that's not an option while I'm developing on both of the project at the same time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue has been fixed in NetBeans 11.1